# Daylight saving disturbed Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: 8.0, sync, exchange

This weekend daylight saving time was applied in Germany. This interrupted my company's email account from syncing with the Exchange Server. Colleagues using iPhone or Android didn't report problems - unfortunately I don't know other colleagues with Windows Phone devices. As a workaround removing and re-adding the account solved the problem for me.
My other company's account running Office365.com worked fine.

Is this a known problem? What can I do as a user to avoid such problems? Or can this only be fixed by the IT department?

(I have a HTC 8X / Windows Phone 8.)

I had configured the "Automatically set date/time" setting.

Comment: I've not seen that behaviour - do you know which version of Exchange you're connected to?

Comment: Found one colleague using Windows Phone (Lumia 820), too. He also did not experience Problems. AFAIK it's Exchange 2010 SP3.

Comment: Are you using the option to set automatically the date+time?

Comment: Yes (added it to the question).

Comment: Colleague of mine (using HTC HD7 / Windows Phone 7) had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work at recently experienced this problem as well, coincidental with the daylight savings time change (interestingly enough, in Germany). However, the users who experienced problems were all BlackBerry users. iOS/Android users were apparently unaffected (or never reported a problem). I don't know if we have any WP users in EMEA...

The symptom was that e-mail messages would be pushed to the BlackBerry about an hour late. If I recall correctly, we restarted our BlackBerry management servers to solve the problem.

For the record, it is fairly well known that computing devices will not talk to each other politely if their clocks are off by more than 5 or 10 minutes. Since we experienced only users connected to our *Germany* Exchange and BlackBerry servers experienced any problems, and since you experienced a similar issue at the same time, it's possible that the clocks on some of Germany's internet backbone routers didn't update to daylight savings time correctly. One well-placed router with an out of date firmware could toss the whole country into disarray come Daylight Savings Time.

In the case of WP connecting directly with Exchange ActiveSync, you might talk to your IT department just to find out if anyone else had issues as well. If other users are still experiencing this problem, then they can investigate it (and it might be as "simple" as bouncing the Exchange servers). If you're the only one with the problem, then you did the right thing by removing and re-adding the account.

:EDIT:
I forgot to add that I, as WP8 user and a systems administrator, am not aware of any known issues with Exchange ActiveSync and WP getting confused over daylight savings time. None of our WP users in North America experienced any problems with the time change this fall.